# Pop function explanation

Tags: c

I have some push and pop code from class that I am trying to understand, and have a question about the pop function.

This is the node structure:

```
struct NODE
{
    int dataitem;
    struct NODE *link;
};
```

This is the pop function:

```
struct NODE* PopD(struct NODE *SP, int *Data)
{
    struct NODE *temp;

    temp = SP;
    *Data = temp->dataitem;
    temp = temp->link;
    free(SP);

    return temp;
}
```

So my question is what does this line do: `*Data = temp->dataitem;`

Why does it take the `dataitem` value into `Data` when it isn't used later in the method?

Comment: It copies the linked list top-node  data value to the address held in the `Data` pointer parameter. As a bonus, it also invokes undefined behavior when you pass an empty list (i.e. a `NULL` value in SP) or a null data target (`NULL` value in `Data`). See if you can spot [the difference](http://pastebin.com/yP54U5cg)

Comment: @WhozCraig - hehe, nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is returned via the `Data` parameter. The return value is used to update the stack pointer. The code is presumably supposed to be used like this:

```
struct NODE *stack = NULL;

// push some items
// ...

// pop one
int data;
stack = PopD(stack, &data);
printf("%d\n", data);
```

Answer (score 1):

The person calling this function will pass in a pointer to a integer - expecting that integer to be filled with the top most integer on your stack.

i.e.

```
int x;
stack = PopD(stack, &x);
printf("Top of stack was %d\n", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value contained in the top of the stack is returned via the output argument when you pop the top item of the stack.

It could be useful to the calling function.